# Connect to Authenticated URL using FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

I am using FreeMarker template engine to get template from external URL which requires basic authentication. For this I am setting the template loader to a URLTemplateLoader and providing my implementation of getURL() method.

```
configuration.setTemplateLoader(new URLTemplateLoader() {
protected URL getURL(String templateName) {
 URL url = null;
url = new URL(URL where template resides);
return url;
} }
```

I am able to get the template in case the URL does not require authentication. But i do not see any way to provide username password for the case where URL needs authentication. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the new URL(String path) constructor which was restricting me to provide authentication data. Instead, java.net.URL class contains a constructor which allows you to pass URLStreamHandler. I had to write my own handler which extends the handler provided by the Java/container at runtime and provide my own implementation of openConnection() method of handler class.

You need to override openConnection() method as this is the one which is used by freemarker when it tries to load the template.

Thanks.